# Update Column in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I would like to update columns in QGIS something like making MAPINFO . Contains , is Within, intersects ) and get values ​​such as sum, avg, propsum , count

Is it possible to do this with any tool in QGIS? I already tried several ways but to no avail.

Comment: You should clarify how mapinfo update column. Then you will receive an answer from QGIS expers.

Answer (score 1):

In the Field Calculator - Geometry

[image]